# Can I make eclipse's explorer view "slide" to the branch like VS does?

Tags: eclipse, package, explorer

When a large project in eclipse has many branches it often expands quite long to the right until you are in your class. Visual Studio (2010 at least) "slides" the view along so that I can see the branch I'm interested in.
With eclipse I always have to manually move the bottom slider and/or adjust the width of the explorer view to see my branch/package. Can I make it focus on my class or the package I am interested in?

Answer (score 0):

In the project explorer View this option :

[image]

Make eclipse follow the current open file in the project structure.

Comment: Yes, I did that, thank you. But that's not what I need.
E.g. I often have to collapse all projects, open one working set to refresh all of its sources. And when I enter one of those really deep down classes/files, they open up again, yes.
But then there's mostly white space in the package explorer until I move the slider to the right. Visual Studio e.g. did move that slider automaticly when I had to make C#.